# If prime a generated no collisions, Can I conclude the same for prime b > a?

Tags: hash, language-agnostic, primes

If I found the smallest prime that gives me no collisions in a custom hashing array. Can I conclude that I won't get any collisions for **any** prime bigger than that aswell, given the exact same input?

Comment: No. Please give your hashing function, but to illustrate with a simple `mod p`. For `p=5` there is no collision between `7` and `21`. But these two collide (have the same remainder) if you move to the bigger prime `p=7`.

Comment: @Thilo I only do input integer mod number of containers. So yes, simple mod p. Your comment already cleared it up then :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

To illustrate with a simple `x mod p`: For `p=5` there is no collision between 8 and 22 (which end up in buckets 3 and 2). But these two collide if you move to the bigger prime `p=7` (bucket 1 for both).